# Zend Frameworks services class not accessable

Tags: frameworks, service

I have created a class service_community in services folder of zend framework but when i am creating object of same it is giving fatal error of class not found.
My php version is 5.3.6
Development was done on windows 7 using xampp and it is working fine out there however when moved to linux this error occurs